# What's the deal with Laravels date casting?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I'm battling a frequently mentioned problem with the casting of date (optionally datetime) fields from Models in Laravel 8. As I use many time-based operations and functions I need the functionality of DateTime or Carbon in my code, however, instantiating them over the MySQL Y-m-d format is impractical.

Laravels documentation recommends using casts as the most elegant solution, I am unfortunately unable to make it work in any way, whatever I do the dates stay as strings. Many SO answers recommend using `protected $dates`, which seems to be only mentioned in Laravel 5.3 documentation and seems to be deprecated, Laravel 8 mentions `protected $casts`, but neither of these attributes works for me. Some answers also mention, that none of these solutions worked for them and that the use of mutators and accessors is the only solution working, but that to me looks like an unnecessarily difficult solution for a simple problem. To make matters worse, Laravel mentions that `created_at` and `updated_at` fields are cast to Carbon by default, but they also appear and act as strings.

What is truly the optimal approach for Laravel 8? Is `protected $dates` deprecated? Why are there so many cases of `protected $casts` not working? Is there any hidden configuration to be edited to make it work which I am missing? I'll appreciate any input or experiences.

Comment: Let's back up. When you say "they also appear and act as strings", how are you determining this? If you output them, they will automatically be stringified via PHP's `__toString`. Try `dd()`ing a `created_at` date and it should come out as a Carbon object.

Comment: I tried `dd()`, `var_dump()` and `php artisan tinker` straight output, always a string. Out of curiosity I tried casting tinyints to booleans, no change as well, maybe the casts themselves are generally not working properly? Still no clues...

Comment: I use casts pretty extensively without issues, including Laravel 8. (Yes, `$dates` got replaced by the more comprehensive `$casts` functionality.) Can you show us your model with the `$casts` definition?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, although `dd()` and `var_dump()` and other examination methods specifically describe the attributes as strings when examining the whole model instance, I made the mistake of not examining each attribute individually.

**Only after calling an attribute** directly it "mutates" to the required type (be it Carbon or boolean or whatever). This is valid for all of the `$casts` elements, not only dates and datetimes.

What needs to be pointed out is the necessary nesting of the model instances inside arrays when passing them to blade templates, otherwise, they become arrays and lose the model capabilities including the casts.

A note is also that `$dates` are not used (although not deprecated, they still work) and documented anymore, the `$casts` are the more general and preferred method, as pointed out by @ceejayoz.